# reading an xml file in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm using a tutorial to read a local xml file. However, I don't get any results. The Code I'm using is:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>W3Schools Internal Note</h1>
<div>
<b>To:</b> <span id="to"></span><br>
<b>From:</b> <span id="from"></span><br>
<b>Message:</b> <span id="message"></span>
</div>

<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","test.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

document.getElementById("to").innerHTML=
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("to")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
document.getElementById("from").innerHTML=
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("from")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[xml file[test.xml]]

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <movies>
<to>We're the millers</to>
<from>2012</from>
<body>2012</body>
</movies>
```

somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to deploy your two files into some http server.
Ajax call can not access for local file system because of the security issue.
after you deploy them, you should test like: `http://localhost/test.html`

The 2nd problem is you need to remove the xml head, otherwise they browser will treat test.xml as text not xml.

```
<movies>
  <to>We're the millers</to>
  <from>2012</from>
  <body>2012</body>
</movies>
```